# Как работает execlp, что за последний аргумент NULL?

Tags: linux, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
 printf("Poczatek\n");
 // что за последний аргумент, я читал, что это
 // какой-то указатель, никак к сожалению понять не могу. 
 execlp("ls", "ls", "-a", NULL); 
 printf("Koniec\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> я читал, что это какой-то указатель, никак к сожалению понять не могу

Попробуем прочитать [man execlp](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=0&topic=execlp) вместе:

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

> Параметр const char *arg и аналогичные записи в функциях execl,
>   execlp, и execle подразумевают параметры arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Все
>   вместе они описывают один или нескольких указателей на строки,
>   заканчивающиеся NULL, которые представляют собой список параметров,
>   доступных исполняемой программе. Первый параметр, по соглашению,
>   должен указывать на имя, ассоциированное с файлом, который надо
>   исполнить. Список параметров должен заканчиваться NULL.

Обратите внимание на последнее предложение. Оно означает, что NULL используется для индикации конца списка аргументов. Это один из общих механизмов сказать "больше агрументов нет" при вызове функций с переменным числом аргументов.

---

Кстати, вы понимаете, что при успешном запуске `ls` вот сюда вы никогда не попадёте?

```
printf("Koniec\n");
```

Comment: Я все понимал, кроме NULL. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Последний аргумент функции execlp - NULL является признаком окончания списка аргументов. Функция execlp возвращает 0 при успешной загрузке нового приложения, а при ошибке возвращает -1.

Comment: "*Функция execlp возвращает 0 при успешной загрузке нового приложения*" - ни в коем случае. Функции семейства `exec*` **замещают** текущий процесс новым, поэтому в случае успеха "возврата" из них случиться не может в принципе.